# My function is too long. In order to pass class I need < 18 lines

Tags: python, function

So I am a total beginner yet this is 100% my code and I am proud of it. Now mind you I need a little cleaning up, however it does what I want it too. My issue is this: In order to turn this in for credit, one of the things is that procedures(functions) should not contain more than 18 lines. My function gameCont() has many more. Would anyone have suggestions on how I could shorten it up? Additionally I am obviously challenged when it comes to function parameters so any help is appreciated. Please be gentle as I am BRAND NEW! :)

```
game1 = "When dealing with SCUBA diving there are many dangers to consider. The very first one is _1_. \
I mean if you take water into your lungs, you are NOT SCUBA diving. Another is rising to the surface too quickly which could \
result in the _2_. Now this is a funny name, as I am sure when it happens, you dont feel 'bendy'. Let's also consider Nitrogen Narcosis.\
If you dont know what that is, well when you are very deep and your body is absorbing more nitrogen than it is used to, you can get \
feeling kinda _3_ feeling as though you just drank not one, but _4_ martinis"
game1_answers = ["drowning", "bends", "drunk", "2"]

game2 = "When you first learn to dive you are taught to do dives within a no DECOmpression limit(NDL). \n This means you do not want to \
stay that deep too long or you will rack up _1_. \n If you DO stay longer than what the NDL allows, you will have an obligation to \
take your time getting to the surface allowing that _2_ gas to leave your body. If you were taking IN gas you may call it \
in-gassing, but when you are decompressing, it may be called _3_-gassing. You are taught also, how to read _4_"
game2_answers = ["deco", "nitrogen", "off", "tables"]

game3 = "Equipment used by cold water divers such as myself are as such. On my head I would wear a _1_. To help regulate the breathing\
pressure from my SCUBA tank I would use a _2_. To help me propel through the water I would place_3_ on my feet. Considering \
we cannot see underwater I need to be wearing a _4_ on my face. Diving in the tropic, many people would use wetsuits, however it's\
very cold where I dive so we wear _5_ suits."
game3_answers = ["hood", "regulator", "fins", "mask", "dry"]

def howManyTries():
    gameTries = raw_input("Thanks for giving my quiz a try, how many attempts do you want? ")
    return int(gameTries)


def game_choice(): #this function is used to determin which difficulty the user wants and returns the proper game and answer list
    user_input = raw_input("Greetings. This is my Udacity project for fill in the blanks. Which one of my options would you like?\
 easy, hard, or hardest? Please take note of capitalization  ")# this will define the user_input variable to raw input placed in by user
    print ("\n" * 20)# just something to clean up the screen
    print "Decided to choose " + user_input + '?' " Well " + user_input + " it is"# this confirms to the user which difficulty they chose.
    print ""
    print ""
    if user_input == "easy": #easy returns game1 and game1 answers
        return game1, game1_answers
    elif user_input == "hard": # hard returns game2 and game2 answers
        return game2, game2_answers
    elif user_input == "hardest": #hardest returns game3 and game 3 answers
        return game3, game3_answers
    else:
        print "It seems that " + user_input + " is not a valid response" #in case the user doesnt choose or spell choice correctly

def gameCont():
    blanks = 1 #this assings blank to 1 which will tell the user which blank they are guessing in below prompt
    attempts = howManyTries() #this calls the howManyTries function for a user choice integer
    quiz, answers = game_choice() #this returns 2 values (game# and game# answers)
    while attempts > 0: #while attempts (called from function) is greater than 0 we will loop this
        print quiz #prints the chosen quiz for user updated each time the loop runs with correct answer
        print("\n" * 10) #clears some more screen to loook better for the user
        guess = raw_input("Reading the above paragraph, What would your guess be for _" + str(blanks) + "_") #asks for guess for current blank which always starts at 1
        print("\n" * 10) #clears some more screen to loook better for the user
        if guess == answers[blanks - 1]: #because indexing count starts at zero, and blanks start at 1 this will check if answer is equal to blanks - 1
            print "As you can see your correct choice has replaced the variable, great job!!"#this will print if the guess is correct
            quiz = quiz.replace("_" + str(blanks) +"_", answers[blanks - 1]) # here is the line of code that replaces the blank with the correct guess
            blanks += 1 # this adds 1 to the blank which will prompt the user to move to the NEXT blank when loop begins again
            if blanks > len(answers):
                print ("\n" * 10)
                print "YOU DID IT!! Here is the final paragraph with all the correct answers"
                print ("\n" * 2)
                print quiz
                break
        elif guess != answers[blanks -1]:  #if the answer does not match the list index
            attempts = attempts - 1 #then we will subtract 1 from the attempts
            print ("\n" * 10)
            print "Oops that is not correct, there should be hints in the paragraph" # lets user know they were wrong
            print "You have " + str(attempts) + " attempts left." # lets the user know how many attempts they have left
            print ""
            if attempts < 1:
                print "Well it looks like you are out of choices, Try again?"
                break
    print "Thanks for playing"




gameCont()
```

Comment: If they allow you to make more functions you could just put some of the larger chunks of your print statements into functions to save some lines

Comment: You have sections with 3-4 print statements giving you a lot of length. Each of those sections could be moved onto one line.

Comment: Or define the full string as a constant and refer to it later

Comment: Code review *clap clap*

Answer (score 2):

Two suggestions:

- Delegate tasks that are accomplished by your function to smaller functions. So, for example, if you had a function that needed perform task A and performing that task could be divided into tasks B, C, and D, then create helper functions and call them inside of the function that does task A.
- You have long strings, maybe store them somewhere else?  Create a class just for constant strings of related functions and access that when you need a particular string. It'll make it less likely that you'll make a mistake when you need to use that string in multiple locations.

  ```
  class Constants:
     str1 = "..."
     str2 = "..."

  print(Constants.str1)
  ```

Answer (score 2):

All of the printing that you're doing could be done in a separate function

```
def game_print(newlines_before, text, newlines_after) 
    print ("\n" * newlines_before + text + "\n" * newlines_after)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can call a function from inside another function. inside an `if` statement you could call a small new function that just prints some stuff. this should make it easy to get the function size down.

something like this should work:

```
def correct(quiz, blanks):
    print "As you can see your correct choice has replaced the variable, great job!!"
    quiz = quiz.replace("_" + str(blanks) +"_", answers[blanks - 1]) # here is the line of code that replaces the blank with the correct guess
    blanks += 1 # this adds 1 to the blank which will prompt the user to move to the NEXT blank when loop begins again
    if blanks > len(answers):
        print ("\n" * 10)
        print "YOU DID IT!! Here is the final paragraph with all the correct answers"
        print ("\n" * 2)
        print quiz`
```

remember that you still want to break after calling that function in order to exit your loop.